# Should 'last version = x' be a part of tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

As I was going through the Suggested Edits Review queue, I saw several edits which were just updating the 'last stable version = vX.Y' part of tag wikis (like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1098102).

So my question for meta is: is it a good practice to put this information on tag wikis?

For very stable/mature projects, it might not change often, but for many FOSS projects, it's always moving. So it's a chore to maintain, and can become a way to harvest points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I say no. All of that information *should* be available at the site(s) linked along with the wiki, and those should give better real time version numbers.

However, in the case of version specific tags, like [ios5](/questions/tagged/ios5), the wiki in my opinion should not only give a very specific version number, but also possibly some documentation on what that version entails.